# Clearing XML file, but only some lines are deleted

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to clear xml lines that contain the string "s". I've implemented this method but it only deletes half of the lines.

```
public void clearResults(String s) {
    try {
        File inputFile = new File("src/resources/config.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        for(int i=0; i<doc.getElementsByTagName(s).getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName(s).item(i);

            element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);

            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(inputFile));
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the content of the "src/resources/config.xml" file and the result you get when you run your code. Also, you should save the result only once after the `for()` loop, not on every iteration inside the `for()` loop.

Comment: You are transforming and writing the entire document inside the loop, for every element found in the parsed document.  Move all of your transformation code outside of the loop.